# Why my android wlan0 network interface has no default gateway?

Tags: c#, android, network-programming

**What I am trying to do : find the IP of the Wi-Fi hotpost the android is connected to.**

I'm using Unity3D with c# and here is my code to get infos about my wlan0 interface : 
[Code to get everything about wlan0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eH6E.png)

```
        NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        .Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Debug.LogWarning($"Up Interface = {ni.Name} " +
        $"has {ni.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Count} gateway adresses " +
        $"& has {ni.GetIPProperties().DhcpServerAddresses.Count} DHCP Adresses " +
        $"& has {ni.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses.Count} DNS adresses");

    var gateways = ni.GetIPProperties()?.GatewayAddresses
        .Select(g => g?.Address)
        .Where(a => a != null);

    foreach(var g in gateways)
        Debug.LogWarning($"ip of defaut gateway = {g.MapToIPv4()}");

    foreach(var d in ni.GetIPProperties()?.DhcpServerAddresses)
        Debug.LogWarning($"ip of dhcp = {d.MapToIPv4()}");

    foreach (var d in ni.GetIPProperties()?.DnsAddresses)
        Debug.LogWarning($"ip of dns = {d.MapToIPv4()}");
```

When I launch this code on my Pico VR Headset, here is the result :
[No gateway, no DHCP, no DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb6yO.png) (and yes my headset is connected to a Wifi)

> Up Interface = wlan0 has 0 adresses & has 0 DHCP Adresses & has 0 DNS adresses

1. Why is there 0 default gateway on android ? (on PC it is working, I can find the IP of my Wi-Fi Hotspot).

   2. How can I get the IP of the Wi-Fi hotspot the android is connected to ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer for "why the wlan0 has no default gateway"

but I have found an answer for "find the IP of the Wi-Fi hotpost the android is connected to" :

```
public string GetHotspotIP()
{
    IPAddress myIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault();
    Debug.LogWarning($"DNS Host Adress = {myIP}");

    string ipString = myIP.MapToIPv4().ToString(); //ie : 192.168.48.165
    string[] ipParts = ipString.Split('.'); //ie : { "192", "168", "48", "165"}
    return string.Concat(ipParts[0], ".", ipParts[1], ".", ipParts[2], ".", "1"); //ie : 192.168.48.1
}
```